# storing data efficiently using Shiny app

Tags: r, local-storage, shiny

I am new to `R`and `Shyni`. I created on my local an app which reads as a `csv`a large file. But each time I run the app, the line `read.csv(my_large_file...)` takes long time. How can I prevent my app to fetch each time the data but instead store it in some memory cache ?

Comment: You can use save(df, "mydf.RData"), and load("mydf.RData") to speed the process up, but it doesn't really matter because once the app is deployed somewhere it only has to load once. If you are performing grouping/summarization on the data, you can do the summaries once and load the summary files. Without more detail and a workable example, it's hard to give more help than that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give You some idea how You can solve this situation:

1. Read the csv file outside of the shiny App (not in server!) and read it using `fread()` function from `data.table` package (it is very fast in reading files)

Or

2. Use the solution of @ConCave: use `save(df, "mydf.RData")`, and `load("mydf.RData")`